# Почему может не работать метод collapse?

Tags: java, android, уведомления, android-notification

Мне нужно после нажатия на кнопку, которая прикреплена к `push notification`, чтобы `StatusBar` сворачивался.

Для этого нашел [вот такой метод](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966540/how-to-hide-notification-panel-after-sending-a-pendingintent-to-service-in-a-not/16978341#16978341)

```
private void expandStatusBar(Context context){
    Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 2");

    try
    {
        Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 3");

        Object service  = context.getSystemService("statusbar");
        Class<?> statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 16)
        {
            Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 4");

            Method collapse = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapse");
            collapse.setAccessible(true);
            collapse.invoke(service);
        }
        else
        {

            Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 5");

            Method collapse2 = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
            collapse2.setAccessible(true);
            collapse2.invoke(service);
        }
    }catch(Exception ignored){}
}
```

Я его запускаю сразу после того как юзер нажимает на кнопку:

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(0);
Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 1");
expandStatusBar(context);
new ModelViewer(context).openFileIfAvailable();
```

Протестировал и в логах все проходит `1,2,3,4`, но шторка не сворачивается...

Но в коде подчеркивает вот эту строку:

```
Object service  = context.getSystemService("statusbar");
```

и говорит, что "statusbar" - такого нет... Нужно выбрать из `Context.smth_else` и выбрал `Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE` , но все равно не работает...

Пробовал сделать так:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
```

context.sendBroadcast(it);

Но тоже не получается...

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Comment: Автор же написал: `it is hacky` :) Возможно это просто уже не работает. Три года назад работало. Следует избегать таких трюков.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Ну я надеюсь, что это до сих пор работает) Может просто я что то пропустил... Но я пробовал и более правильный способ new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS); Но ведь все равно не хочет...

Answer (score 1):

Вот что делаете не так:

1. Пишете лог только ДО вызова критической секции кода
2. Глушите исключения, даже не выводя ничего в лог

Как тогда быть уверенным что код вообще исполняется?